# Do my own villages/cities interrupt my "longest road" in Catan?

Tags: catan

In a monthly game night, my friend interprets the rules to say that if I have a village or city on my road, it reduces the "longest road" length. I interpret the rules as saying that *my* village/city on *my* road does not impact the road length.

Which is the correct interpretation?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

**You are correct.**

Your own cities do not affect your status towards the "Longest Road" You can view the official rules [here](http://www.catan.com/gamerules.html), from pg. 9 (emphasis is mine).

> You can break an **opponent’s** road by building a settlement
>   on an open intersection along his road!

On page 8, in the example, Emily has the longest road card with 7 segments.  She has two houses within those 7 segments.

This was also [answered directly](http://www.catan.com/faq/4607-longest-road-do-my-own-settlements-interrupt-my-continuous-road) in the [online FAQ](http://www.catan.com/faqs/93) as [pointed out](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/35/catan-longest-road-clarification/43#43) by @shemmon.

Answer (score 31):

To affect the road length, the village/city must be from another player.

And it only limits the counting of the road *through* that village/city.  You can count up to the village/city that is not yours.

Also, here's a more official 'no:'
https://www.catan.com/faq/4607-longest-road-do-my-own-settlements-interrupt-my-continuous-road