# Can a settlement disrupt roads in Settlers of Catan

Tags: catan

Let's say my opponent (o) has a road network:

```
o - - - - - o

       |
       x
```

as x, can I:

```
o - - -x- - o
       |
       |
       x
```

?

And break his already existing road?

My question is not whether or not this will break his road; my question is if it is legal for me to build there and break an already-established road.

At a previous game, there was considerable controversy as to whether this was a legal place to build a settlement.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If you build a settlement on his road, you disrupt it yes.

See also: [catan-longest-road-clarification](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/35/catan-longest-road-clarification).

You can build on any place if:

1. You can reach it by road or ship
2. The vacant spot has no neighbouring settlements or cities. (There must be at least one empty spot between two settlements/cities)

Comment: Absolutely correct. The presence of an other player's road does not prevent you from build a settlement there...

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is a legal move you can find an example on page 11 of the Almanac. Essentially as long as a road has a connection to a city it can be broken up.

Comment: -1 for "*Essentially as long as a road has a connection to a city it can be broken up.*" - I'm not 100% sure what you mean by this, but if you mean that once split both parts of the road must be connected to a settlement/city, you are incorrect.

Comment: You should know what I mean by page 11 of the rules.