# In Catan, when a settlement breaks a road. Do the other existing roads sit there? or are they removed?

Tags: catan

**Recently,** I came upon an odd rule that states that a town/city placed in between two enemy roads "displaces" the enemy roads, now let's say there is a large stretch of road with only one town connected. And my opponent places a town in between my roads to "displace" it. Does the side not connected to my town get removed, or does it sit there?

In case you don't understand what I'm trying to say here. I'll provide a simple diagram and I'll restate the problem.

*---B-----#-------A-----

Ok, let's say the asterisk is my town and the hash key is the enemy town. And obviously the dashs are my roads.

Since the enemy town displaces the main road into two different sections(section B and section A). Does section A sit there? or is it removed from the game?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Breaking roads in Settlers of Catan](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/946/breaking-roads-in-settlers-of-catan)

Comment: @ToonKrijthe This is not a duplicate in any way shape or form, my question only mentions a particular circumstance that happens to be related to the Breaking Roads rule. Moreover, the question you mention also points to a particular circumstance that is completely unrelated to my circumstance.

Comment: Not entirely. If you have the longest road, and an enemy town breaks it in two. You have two road segments. It is possible that one of those segments is still te longest road.

Comment: @ToonKrijthe Since road AB is displaced by the enemy town, does segment A get removed from the board because there is nothing connected to it(No towns/cities).

Comment: No it does not. 
You can even build settlements and road segments to it.

Comment: See for the official FAQ: http://www.catan.com/faqs/93?page=1

Comment: This isn't a duplicate question. The other question is "Can I break the longest road by building a settlement?" and this question is "If I break a road by building a settlement, do the roads get removed from the game board?"

Comment: @HTMLNoob In Catan, each settlement has three incoming paths. You must have built a road on one of them already in order to build your settlement. All three paths are equally spaced apart. Which path is "the side not connected to my town" that you describe in the question? The one-dimensional diagram doesn't help me understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at http://www.catan.com/service/game-rules I can't find the word 'displace' so i'm not sure exactly what rule you are referring to. So I will answer your question by explaining what would happen quoting the rules.

Building a settlement.

> You must meet 2 conditions when building a settlement: (1) Your
>   settlement must always connect to 1 or more of your own roads. (2) You
>   must observe the Distance Rule.

There is nothing there about removing roads from the map.

in the Longest Road section it states.

> You can break an opponent’s road by building a settlement on an
>   unoccupied intersection along his road!

This might apply in the example you have given.  Your longest road length will no be either section A or B, depending which is longer.  There is nothing in the rules about removing roads from the map here either.

Comment: Might want to specifically add that section A can still be built on; he can build more roads and settlements over there.

Comment: I didn't cover that as the question was about if the road is in two section or is removed.  As its not removed then all the usual rules for building settlements would still apply.